# Change format date in Java does not work correctly

Tags: java, java.util.date

```
public class CronoProgrammaForm {
    ...
    java.util.Date datPreIniLav;

    //getter and setter
    ...
}
```

Main

```
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

 cronoProgrammaForm.setDatPreIniLav(df.parse(df.format(cronoProgrammaForm.getDatPreIniLav())));
```

*cronoProgrammaForm.getDatPreIniLav()* is 2015-10-14 *df.format(cronoProgrammaForm.getDatPreIniLav())* is 14/10/2015

Why

*sdf.parse(df.format(cronoProgrammaForm.getDatPreIniLav()))*

is Wed Oct 14 00:00:00 CEST 2015?! I would it was 14/10/2015

Comment: because `SimpleDateFormat#parse` does parse the `String` into a `Date`.
I´d guess what you are printing is what `Date#toString` does return, which should match your output. You might want to reformat it with `sdf.format(Date)`. But this isn´t a 100% correct hint, because your question does lack code to answer it correctly.

Comment: What is sdf? You only show the definition for df...

Comment: @KevinEsche, sorry I don't undestand..?

Comment: @Joni, it was my mistake :)

Comment: @DavideFruci how do you print the Date? do you do `...println(Date)` or `println(df.format(Date))`. I am quite sure that you are doing the first one, which does print the `String` representation of the `Date` by using the `Date#toString` method and not the formated `String` representation that you are trying to get.

Comment: @KevinEsche I don't printed the date yet, I saw the result of conversation during debugging. 
The method convert in json the CronoProgrammaForm object and, then, I print the json in the js

Comment: Your debugging output is just going to do a print on the Date as you are just storing a Date variable

Comment: @DavideFruci The `Date` object doesn´t save how it should be formated. If you want a `Date` object to be formated you allways have to format it like you did with `df.format`. The instance of `Date` doesn´t know which format it should use and will allways use the same format, which can be seen by you. In this case you shouldn´t mind because it will just show the output of `Date#toString` in the debugger.

Comment: @KevinEsche, So what should I do to resolve?